# Question on CSS adaptive layout

Tags: css, html, layout, mobile-website

I have a very specific question related to CSS adaptive layout.

I have seen example on certain websites where say you have a 3-column layout shown for a particular resolution (or say desktop)....Now when the screen size reduces (say for a mobile device), the same layout now displays as a 2-column layout.

What are the specific CSS attributes which make this possible and what is the best way to create such adaptive layouts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is known as [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) and is achieved with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: Thx for that...While I am aware of the media query think and it being known as responsive design, my question is what are the specific CSS attributes which help us acheive this and the actual implementation strategies for this ?

Comment: If you want to be specific about which parts of CSS are involved then either "media queries" or "all of CSS". As for strategies, the basics are "Use media queries to provide different layouts for different sizes" and from there you go in to long (long enough to be out of scope for SO) tutorials like the one I linked to.

Comment: I mean CSS media query is a very broad or high-level thing and does not give any idea about the implementation...I am sure there is some specific ways to implement the scenario I have described and guess they don't have to be really long tutorials...

Comment: Also to add...I have already gone through the links/tutorials mentioned by you...They are very theoretical and do not give any kind of implementation ideas..I guess you also answered this question just in a GENERIC way by just pointing those links and are not aware of the actual implementation...

Comment: The first link includes an [entirely non-theoretical example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html). If you don't want generic answers then don't give generic questions. (And don't try to taunt me into spending time building a complete working example just to prove that I do know what I'm talking about).

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you'll find it is not generic...It clearly asks a specific question..."What are the specific CSS attributes ..."

Comment: @testndtv — And, as I said, specifically: media queries.

Comment: Well...I am really not sure if CSS attributes would translate into media queries....As far as I know CSS attributes would mean padding,margin,width, etc

Comment: @testndtv — Those are properties. "Attributes" is not a technical term when it comes to CSS, and the english meaning is "feature". It is media queries that let you do different layouts for different sizes. My other answer ("All of them") can be taken to refer to properties if you did mean properties. Then becomes a "How do I do layout using CSS?" question and has nothing to do with the primary focus of the question (which was about adapting). If you really want that, then you're hitting [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739018/best-way-to-learn-css) territory.

Comment: I hope u atleast trust MSDN..this is what they also think about CSS attributes..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531207(v=vs.85).aspx Also the duplicate question pointed by u is completely different from what i have asked here...

Comment: @testndtv — Don't trust MSDN, it has many issues (including a lot revolving around conflating "X and Microsoft's non-standard add-ons to X"). If the question stops being about "How to do different things for different displays" and becomes "How to do layout", then it is a duplicate. And if it doesn't, then the answer is "media queries".

Comment: I am not really sure what u trust..But hope u atleast trust these 2 links; http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/css-attributes/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html or not sure if u trust just what u say or feel !!!

Comment: The specification is talking about attribute selectors (i.e. CSS selectors that match HTML attributes) not properties. Web Monkey is talking about HTML attributes that are commonly used in CSS selectors or have embedded CSS in them (the heading is just a bit misleading).